# QT Designer pushButton link to QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, attribute-table, feature-layer

I want to build a custom Toolbar with Plugin Builder 3 for QGIS. I managed to create the necessary folders and files and I can load my UI into QGIS:

The UI looks very simple with only two buttons like this:

<kbd>Pushbutton1</kbd> <kbd>Pushbutton 2</kbd>

---

There is a point layer in QGIS and I want both buttons to work with this layer.
The AttributeTable of the point layer consists of elements like: ID, class, description

- If I press **Pushbutton1** and click at a location on the map canvas I want to create a new feature in the point layer that belongs to **class A**
- If I press **Pushbutton2** and click at a location on the map canvas I want to create a new feature in the point layer that belongs to **class B**

Here is what I tried so far:

my_toolbar.py

```
# Import necessary modules
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *


# Define a function to add a new feature to the layer
def add_feature():
    # Get the active layer
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    
    # Get the layer's feature count
    count = layer.featureCount()
    
    # Create a new feature
    feature = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(0, 0)))
    feature.setAttribute('ID', count + 1)
    feature.setAttribute('class', 'class_entry1')
    
    # Add the feature to the layer
    layer.startEditing()
    layer.addFeature(feature)
    layer.commitChanges()
    
# Create a new button in QGIS
button = pushButton1('Add Feature')

# Connect the button to the add_feature function
button.clicked.connect(add_feature)

# Add the button to the QGIS toolbar
iface.addToolBarWidget(button)
```

The code is for only one button so far to test it, but if I run the code nothing happens, I don't even get any errors that help me find a solution.
Once the code works, I just want to repeat it for the 2nd button.
I also don't know how I can change the code that the user can define a point by clicking at the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a widget with two `QPushButton` on it, and then call `show()` to display the widget:

```
btn1 = QPushButton('Add Feature for Layer1')
btn2 = QPushButton('Add Feature for Layer2')
gui = QWidget()
vbl = QVBoxLayout()
vbl.addWidget(btn1)
vbl.addWidget(btn2)
gui.setLayout(vbl)

# Define a function to add a new feature to the layer
def add_feature():
    # add your code here
    ...
    
btn1.clicked.connect(add_feature)
gui.show()
```

Run this code in your QGIS python editor. Now you can test it by checking the message given in the `LogMessages`>`Python Error` Window:

[image]